# How to encode the identity function in ANF?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to grok ANF (administrative normal form) but I'm having trouble understanding the translation from lambda terms. Consider this lambda term: `λx.x`. How do you encode it in ANF? `x` is a variable, but a lambda body must be a let binding or a function application in ANF, according to the ANF grammar:

```
EXP ::= VAL VAL
      | let VAR = EXP in EXP

VAL ::= λ VAR . EXP
      | VAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form#Grammar) fails to provide the full grammar.
Here is a corrected version:

```
EXP ::= VAL
      | VAL VAL
      | let VAR = EXP in EXP

VAL ::= λ VAR . EXP
      | VAR
```

This means the identity function is a fixed point of the A-normalizer function, i.e. it is just the same `λx. x`. More on this can be found [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/a-normalization/).